# Tkinter: Auto scroll Text box on a specific click on the text box on its left in Tkinter. Similar to Navigation Pane in MS Word

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to auto scroll a text box on the right on a specific click on a word on the left (similar to Navigation pane in MS Word).
I added hyperlink to link every word in the section, and now I want that when I click the word, it can extract that word, and that word is sent to any function which will return `tkinter.see(index/line(word))` and enable auto scroll. But I am unable to extract the word on the click.

See the output that I have:
[image: screenshot]

I want that when I click on *Basic Transaction* it scrolls to the basic transactions and when I click on *Payment* it scrolls to the payment section.

My Question to the Specific part:
I want to extract the section name when I click on it. Then I can pass that string to the function `click1()` which will auto scroll to find that specific word on the right text box using the `.see` method in tkinter.

I change the framing of the question:
In the above image, on the left text widget, under the Section, if I click on the "Basic Transaction", then how can I print that on the Ipython console(Spyder console)?
And if I click "Payment", how can I print "Payment" on my python console?
Is there any possible way to extract the text of the Mouse-1 click? Something like:

`tag_bind(<Mouse-1>)`
if Mouse-1 clicks:
      `print(wordstart, wordend)` OR `print(text_widget.cget(text))`

Comment: You've told us what you want, but you haven't asked a question. What part of the problem do you need help with?

Comment: In addition to Bryan Oakley's comment, could you make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates your problem? Right now, there is too much code and it is not runnable ('HyperlinkManager' is not defined).

Comment: I have edited the question and the problem I am facing. And also fixed the code which includes the "HyperlinkManager" class.

Comment: There's a lot of unnecessary code in your question. I recommend you reduce the code down a bit more. That's a lot of code to wade through. Also, make sure the code actually runs, which it doesn't currently do. I get `"name 'l12' is not defined`. When I fix that, another error crops up.

Comment: I removed the code and added another similar question to be more specific at the bottom. Is it now okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract the text clicked on, you can indeed use tag bindings. But, instead of trying to find out which portion of text was clicked on, I think it's easier to use a different tag for each section title and bind them separately:

```
import tkinter as tk

def add_hyperlink(section, tag):
    # when you insert text, you can directly give it tags with 
    # text.insert(<index>, <text>, [tag1, tag2, ...])
    text.insert('end', section + '\n\n', ('link', tag))
    text.tag_bind(tag, '<Button-1>', lambda e: print(section))

root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(root)
text.tag_configure('link', foreground='blue', underline=True)

text.insert('1.0', 'SECTIONS\n\n')
add_hyperlink('Basic Transactions', 'basic')
add_hyperlink('Payment', 'payment')

text.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: awesome. this works. did not realize it was this simple. Thanks.